# Вывести блок за пределы контейнера (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

подскажите, как можно вывести картинку за пределы container (во всю ширину), до края body
[код онлайн](https://jsfiddle.net/3zj6vhL0/)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.about-img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.one{background-color: #fcce06;}
.two {background-color: aqua;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 one">
      <div class="about-text-title">Косми́ческое простра́нство, ко́смос (др.-греч. κόσμος «мир», «Вселенная») — относительно пустые участки Вселенной, которые лежат вне границ атмосфер небесных тел. Вопреки распространённым представлениям, космос не является абсолютно пустым пространством:
        в нём есть, хотя и с очень низкой плотностью, межзвёздное вещество (преимущественно молекулы водорода), кислород в малых количествах (остаток после взрыва звезды), космические лучи и электромагнитное излучение, а также гипотетическая тёмная материя.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 two"><img class="about-img" src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=dd5d45248c04618fca067660ec5854e0-l&n=13" alt="about"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Использовать класс container-fluid

Comment: Мне не нужно расширять контейнер. Только блок

Comment: За ширину отвечает width...можно указать в процентах